# Lion : Assigning a fullscreen app to a space

Tags: macos, spaces

With SnowLeopard, I was using spaces, with two spaces. On the second space, I was running a fullscreen application.

I created a shortcut to switch from my first space to the second space : Cmd+1 goes to space 1, Cmd+2 goes to space 2 (displaying my fullscreen app).

I recently upgraded to Lion and cannot reconfigure it to have the same behavior I had with Snow Leopard :

When running my app fullscreen, a new space (sub-space ?) dedicated to this app is created. Now, when pressing Cmd+2, it displays space 2, but it is empty, as my fullscreen app is somewhere else.

How can I make sure my fullscreen app sticks to a space, so that using Cmd+1 and Cmd+2, I can quickly switch between my normal desktop (space 1) and my fullscreen app (space 2) ?

Answer (score 2):

In Lion, the only options you have to manage the order of spaces are...

- **System Preferences → Mission Control → Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use**
- Manually drag spaces in **Mission Control**

The shortcuts to switch between spaces and desktops are set in...

- **System Preferences → Keyboard → Mission Control**

But, you can only set direct shortcuts to **Desktops** - not any space.

[image]

Comment: Also note that more shortcuts come up as you create more desktops. I just realised now. ^^

Comment: @latusaki Yes. That can be a bit confusing when you have only one desktop... :)

Comment: The most confusing thing with mission control is that you can't move your 'main' desktop. Wonder what the engineers at apple were thinking...

Comment: I'm still confused. Let's say I'm working with only one desktop. When running an app in fullscreen, Lion put it in a specific screen : is it possible to directly access this specific screen by a shortcut ?

Comment: @Jérôme  You can click the application icon in the dock or use the applications switcher via CMD-TAB.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > Keyboard . THere you can change the shortcuts. If what you want is possible you should be able to do it from there.